# Como exibir uma variável inteira em um textView e adicionar +1 a ela cada vez que clico em um botão presente na mesma activity?

Tags: java, android, textview

Gostaria que o textView exibisse o valor da variável que criei na MainActivity "int numero = 0".

```
package genesysgeneration.a10;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numero = 0;
    private Button btnMais1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnMais1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);

    }
}
```

Entretanto não consegui fazê-lo, então coloquei 0 para aparecer algo na imagem do emulador e ficar mais fácil de entender o que eu gostaria de fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ao clicar no botão o valor da variável aumentasse em 1 e que o textView fosse atualizado.

Gostaria saber também se era necessário colocar private ou public antes de ter declarado a variável inteira int, tipo:

```
private int numero = 0;
```

ou

```
public int numero = 0;
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.a10.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/tvContador"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:text="+ 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnMais1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar o método `OnClick()` do `button`. Para utilizar este método, você precisa aplicar um [OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) no seu [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

```
package genesysgeneration.a10;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numero = 0;
    private Button btnMais1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnMais1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMais1);
        btnMais1.setOnClickListener(maisHandle);
    }

    View.OnClickListener maisHandle = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             numero += 1; // adiciona +1 na váriavel numero
             TextView.setText(String.valueOf(numero)); // coloca o valor na textview
         }
     }
}
```

Utilizar a variável `numero` como `public` ou `private` não interfere exatamente no que você quer fazer. Isso são níveis de visibilidade ou pra ser mais resumido, diz quem pode acessar ou não.

**Private**: A classe que a criou é a única que pode acessá-la.

**Public**: Todas as classes podem acessar essa variável.

Isso quer dizer que se a variável `numero` fosse definida como `public` na sua `MainActivity` todas as outras classes poderiam acessar ela. Caso contrário, apenas a `MainActivity` poderia acessar esta variável.

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO MANO!!! VLW MESMO!!!

Agora se não for incomodar muito, eu gostaria de saber se eu poderia colocar esse public void fora do "@Override"?

Comment: olha o código agora

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!!!

Em breve tentarei fazer algo parecido com checkBox.